# call python function from c++ (visual studio 2019)

Tags: python, c++

I want to call the function from a python file from the visual studio 2019.
By googling, it looks like I need to use the following function.
I added a "Sample.py" in the same place where the exe is stored for the c++ .

```
int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    // Create some Python objects that will later be assigned values.

    PyObject* pName, * pModule, * pFunc, * pArgs = nullptr, * pValue; 
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"Sample"); 
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName); 
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, (char*)"fun"); 
    pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
}
```

In the "Sample.py" which is placed in the same path as the exe of the c++

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fun(): x = [1,2,3]
y = [2,4,1]
plt.plot(1, 2)
```

And when i run the c++ code, it throws an exception at PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs); saying Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC54B6F3D2 (python37.dll) in ConsoleApplication9.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.
Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
**v** was nullptr.

I just want to know if im missing any thing in my visual studio setup

Because when i change the sample.py to just following without the #import, it works fine

```
def fun():  print("Hello from a function")
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens when you invoke `PyObject_CallFunction(pFunc, nullptr);` ? What you have *should* work regardless, but still, just wondering.

Comment: @WhozCraig : Thankyou for reply. It is same behaviour with your suggested change.

Comment: Always check return values of all functions.

Comment: Just to update the earlier exception is gone. Actually i tried to run the python script from command line and one tab was missing. So now from the windows command line , i can ran the script to display plot and was ok. But when i try with c++, the earlier exception is not seen. But program exits without displaying the chart.

Comment: There is similar post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53822542/plotting-data-generated-in-c-program-using-pythons-matplotlib. There he passes the x and y into function. But still the python script looks the same. If that can plot, not sure why my case it is. @Manatbit could you let me know , if anything else you did (like paths etc) for the plot to display

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following and plotting is ok now !

```
#include <iostream>
#include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\include\Python.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int)
{
    Py_Initialize();//-Initialize python interpreter
    if (!Py_IsInitialized())
    {
        PyRun_SimpleString("print 'inital error!' ");
        return -1;
    }
    //PyRun_SimpleString("print 'inital ok! ");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");//--It is equivalent to the import sys statement in python, sys is to deal with the interpreter
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('./')"); //Specify the directory where pytest.py is located
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.argv = ['python.py']");
    PyObject* pName = NULL;
    PyObject* pMoudle = NULL;//---Store the python module to be called
    PyObject* pFunc = NULL;//---Store the function to be called
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString("Sample"); //Specify the file name to be imported
    pMoudle = PyImport_Import(pName);//--Using the import file function to import the helloWorld.py function
    if (pMoudle == NULL)
    {
        PyRun_SimpleString("print 'PyImport_Import error!' ");
        return -1;
    }
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pMoudle, "fun");//--Find the hello function in the python reference module helloWorld.py
    PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);//---Call hello function

    Py_Finalize();//---Clean up the python environment and release resources
    return 0;
}
```

The plot script in Sample.py is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def fun():
    x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.02)
    y = np.sin(x)
    plt.axis([-np.pi, np.pi, -2, 2])
    plt.plot(x, y, color="r", linestyle="-", linewidth=1)
    plt.show()
```